# How to stop enum from going out of bounds?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I'm still learning the ropes with C# programming. I am trying to write an application to solve [Knight's Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_Tour) but have run into some grief when trying to get possible future positions for the knight.

For positions I am using a very simple struct:

```
public struct Position
{
    public enum BoardRank { A = 1, B, C, D, E, F, G, H }; 
    public BoardRank X;
    public int Y;
}
```

In the knight class, my `PossibleMoves()` method begins like this:

```
public List<Position> PossibleMoves(Position position)
{
    List<Position> positions = new List<Position>();
    int[] multiply = new int[]{1, -1};
    foreach (int times in multiply)
    {
        try{
            Position possible = new Position();
            possible.X = position.X + (Behaviour.X * times);
            possible.Y = position.Y + (Behaviour.Y * times);
            positions.Add(possible);
        }
    ...
```

For position = A1 and times = -1, you can see how Behaviour.X could quickly fall out of bounds, but I assumed this would have been picked up by the try block.

I tried adding a `{get; set;}` on the enum declaration but that threw some useless syntax errors in VS2010.

Is there anything else I can try here to stop my enum from going out of bounds?

Comment: Enumerations are pretty much just a way to name integers and are backed by integer types, meaning that you need to check to see if the value assigned to the enum variable is valid.

Comment: syntax errors - ain't nobody got time fo dat!

Answer (score 9):

> I assumed this would have been picked up by the try block.

Nope. Enums in C# are "named numbers" effectively. They're *not* a complete set of values for the type.

> Is there anything else I can try here to stop my enum from going out of bounds?

You can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to check whether a value exists in the original enum. I would personally stop using public fields, and instead make `Position` immutable - then validate the value in the constructor. You could also have methods such as `WithX` which returned a new value based on the current value with just `X` changing. While you've got public fields, you're never going to be able to trust that any particular value is valid though.

Comment: Validate the value in which constructor? My position is contained within a struct, which I understand structs can't contain methods. I'll look into immutable in a moment as I haven't read up on it at all yet...
Regarding the public fields, security is not the primary concern here, I will figure out the access modifiers once I have the logic right!

Comment: @user2379725 Structs can contain methods.

Comment: Hmm so they can. Thanks again Matthias. Do you know what constructor Jon Skeet is talking about in his post? The Position struct doesn't have a constructor currently, did he mean that I can and should have one, like this:

    public v3Position(BoardRank boardrank, int file)
    {
        X = boardrank;
        Y = file;
    }

Comment: @user2379725: I'm suggesting that you *create* a constructor. The reason for not using public fields isn't for security - it's for cleaner design, making a type easier to use properly and harder to use badly.

Comment: @user2379725 As Jon wrote in his comment you can create a constructor and validate `BoardRank boardrank` in it with `Enum.IsDefined`. You can handle invalid values properly then to construct a valid `Position` instance, either by throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or replacing them with accurate values.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to use modulo to keep the values within a specific range:

```
possible.X = (position.X + (Behaviour.X * times)) % ((int)BoardRank.H + 1);
```

This way I am not sure whether an enum is the best solution here, as we're working with integers anyway. The numbers must be a sequence with *no gaps* and you have to make sure you take the *highest defined enum value plus one*. Thus, if you add a `I` to your enum, you need to change the modul.

Here I have a very simple program to illustrate how it works:

```
enum Foo { A, B, C }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i % ((int)Foo.C + 1));
    }
}
```

As you see we take `i` *modulo* `C + 1` which makes `C`'s *integer value* the actual range maximum. This is the output:

> 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0

Comment: This looks really interesting, @matthias-meid. I have been looking for a way to iterate over all possibilities of operators, and yours looks quite elegant. Now if only I could get it to happen in a two dimensional array...?

Comment: @user2379725 I can't see a two-dimensional array. Basically, you can do the modulo for each dimension separately by computing `x = xnew % xmax` and `y = ynew % ymax` to get your `(x, y)` for two dimensions. Does that help somehow?

Comment: Give me a moment to have a tinker and I'll come back and edit this. You can't see a 2d array because I haven't employed one, and I haven't employed one because I hadn't thought of doing this

Comment: I haven't figured out a way to make modulo spit out the following sequence: -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2. It wouldn't be so difficult if 0 were a possibility, but it isn't...any ideas, Matthias? I'd up-rate all your comments so far if I had 15 rep, you've been awesome!

Comment: @user2379725 You can't implement a sequence *with a gap* solely with modulo. **What `BoardRank` values do actually exist (-2 to 2 without 0?)?** If you had *no gap*, you can make them positive for modulo and subtract the delta afterward. For instance with -2 to 2 it were: `d := -2`, then `x = (xnew + d) % (x_max + d + 1) - d`. In case you *do have gaps* (0 for instance) you need to work it out the hard way with `Enum.IsDefined` and rules to handle invalid integers as Jon suggest.